# Object is not a function using async in sailsjs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sails.js, synchronous, waterline

```
    test: function(req,res){
    current = [];
    var keyrez;
        async.each(keyz,function(keyfor,callback){
            Trigger.count().where({key:keyfor}).exec(function(err,nb){
                console.log("count=" +nb +" for "+keyfor);
                var randm = Math.floor((Math.random() * nb));
                console.log(nb);


                Trigger.findOne().skip(randm).where({
                    key: keyfor,
                    status:'true'
                }).exec(function(e,rr){
                    console.log("returning value " + rr.value);
                    current.push(rr.value);
                    callback();

                });

            });

        }, function(error){
            if(error){
                console.log('error');
            }
            else{
                console.log('not getting here')
                console.log(current);
            }
        });

},
```

I'm trying to make this synchronous so I can get "current" which is an array and is filled by this function.
So as you can see I've tried async.each but I get this TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: Which line are you getting it for?